# MacOS X installer and Disk Utility does not recognize the SSD drive on MBA 1,1

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I've tryed to upgrade my original MBA with SSD ([item on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/190789550305?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)), but Disk Utility in the MacOS installer does not recognize it. I've tryed to boot from Ubuntu Live USB, but GParted does see it too.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

df -h output:
[image]

Comment: run "df -h" in command line, then post the results please.

Comment: I've added df -h output

Comment: If neither DiskUtil nor GParted are able to see the SSD it's either not working or not connected properly. Do you have an external USB enclosure you could put the SSD in to give it a try?

Comment: No, I haven't. I bought one and waiting for it's shipment

Comment: Have you tried installing the SSD in the HDD bay, rather than the optical drive bay? My SSD didn't work when I put it in the optical drive bay, so I moved the SSD to the HDD bay and moved the HDD to the optical drive bay.

Comment: I've tryed to put it only as the primary drive, because MBA has no optical bay.